# When using Moq, are mocked interfaces implemented methods supposed to execute?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, moq

I am new to using Moq and have not unit tested in about 5 years.  Many things have changed.

I'm trying to wrap my head around the basics.

I have an interface.

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Log(string message)
}
```

And this interface is implemented in the following way.

```
public class MyLogger : ILogger
{
    public virtual void Log(string message)
    {
        StaticClass.StaticMethodNotToBeCalled<ILogger>().Log(message);
    }
}
```

I am testing the following logic.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyMethod(int z)
    {
        var logger = new MyLogger();

        if(z == 5) 
        {
           logger.Log("it is true");

           return true;
        }

        logger.Log("it is false);

        return false;
    }
}
```

My test looks like the following.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_MyMethod()
{
    var mock = new Mock<ILogger>();

    mock.Setup(y => y.Log(It.IsAny<string>()).Verifiable();

    var o = new MyClass();

    var result = o.MyMethod(5);

    Assert.IsTrue(result);        

    mock.Verify();

}
```

The issue I am running into is the static method being called in the implementation of the ILogger interface.

I am guessing I just do not have a good understanding on what exactly a mock should.

What I would like to do is that any time ILogger.Log it is overridden and does not call that static method.

Is this possible?

Am I going about this a wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a Mock based on the `ILogger` interface, but you are not injecting the Mock into your `MyClass` instance.  When `MyClass` executes it uses an instance of `Logger` instead of your `ILogger` mock.

Consider something like this for your class instead:

```
public class MyClass
{

    private ILogger logger;
    public MyClass(ILogger loggerInstance)
    {
        logger=loggerInstance;
    }
    public MyMethod(int z)
    {

        if(z == 5) 
        {
           logger.Log("it is true");

           return true;
        }

        logger.Log("it is false);

        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that in the constructor of MyClass you are now accepting an instance of a class that implements the `ILogger` interface.  This allows you to inject your mock object in place of the actual concrete Logger:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_MyMethod()
{
    var mock = new Mock<ILogger>();

    mock.Setup(y => y.Log(It.IsAny<string>()).Verifiable();

    var o = new MyClass(mock.Object);

    var result = o.MyMethod(5);

    Assert.IsTrue(result);        

    mock.Verify();

}
```

*Dependency injection* is the concept that you're missing in your scenario.  It is imperative in many cases to writing unit-testable code.

Comment: Hey Thanks this works.  I guess I'm bummed the mocking isn't more global in nature, but that's fine.  I was originally avoiding doing anything in the constructor because the Class in this instance is a Controller, but this pattern still works fine.